# Jquery Hover show/hide issue

Tags: hover, hide, show

Im trying to setup so that when you hover over class .object1 -> in turn should reveal .obj_1 when you are not hovered on it, it should hide .obj_1.  I may be a little off in my code, thanks for the help!.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $(".obj_1 , .obj_2").hide();
      });
      $(".object1").hover(
        function() { $(".obj_1").show(); },
        function() { $(".obj_2").hide(); }
   );
      $(".object2").hover(
        function() { $(".obj_2").show(); },
        function() { $(".obj_1").hide(); }
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple it should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $(".obj_1 , .obj_2").hide();
      });
      $(".object1").hover(
        function() { $(".obj_1").show(); },
        function() { $(".obj_1").hide(); }
   );
      $(".object2").hover(
        function() { $(".obj_2").show(); },
        function() { $(".obj_2").hide(); }
   );
```

The "hover" handler function signature is ( mouseInHandler, mouseOutHandler). 
For object1 you want to show obj_1 on mouseIn, and hide it on mouseOut. 
You don't need to reference obj_2 on object1 hover handlers.

Check out the fiddle I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C94Tq/)

FYI - the hover events act weird when you have complex inner content. ( for example, div within another div and so on ). I advise you to use ["mouseenter"](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and ["mouseleave"](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

UPDATING ANSWER AFTER REALIZING THIS IS A DROP DOWN MENU QUESTION

The drop down menu in CSS is a great example where "hover" won't suffice --> because the submenu disappears once you're not on the link anymore.. and that's not what we want.

It is important to note 3 things about drop down menus :

1. They can (?should?) be achieved purely with CSS
2. The HTML structure is important.

For example, consider the following structure instead :

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="menu">
         <li>
         </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This structure is recursive - you can have infinite levels of submenus - and the mouseenter/mouseleave on the "li" will hold since the submenu is part of the "li" item.

To see this in action have a look in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7k7f/5/)

Please also note that I removed the first "hide" from the onload code, and replaced it with css "display:none" - which resolves flickering on page load ( flickering means - first the submenu shows, and once the page loads, we hide it. )

A css solution would include a selector with "hover" on it ( yes, hover.. )

You can find plenty of blog posts about it while searching in google.

[Here is the first one I found.](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/)

Comment: So if I have a div Ul LI before the actual event = HIDE or SHOW your suggesting to use Mouseenter and mouseleave? Cause your spot on, it doesnt work unless its a simple hierarchy. Could i add, the prior classes??

Comment: Check this, this is how my navigation appears.. entirely it works here, but not in my website... this is frustrating..http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/C94Tq/1/

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script> This is in my Head btw

Comment: You are doing a drop down menu :)  this is an interesting issue. I will update my answer or you can have a peek at http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-dropdown-menu

Comment: I added drop down menu specific example with a fiddle. I advise to resolve the menu with CSS. however, my fiddle shows how JS can be used as well.